# Фоновый процесс на PHP

Tags: php

Как запустить скрипт, который будет работать, даже если пользователей нет на сайте если быть точнее, то мне в будущем будет необходимо подгружать данные с одного сервиса и заливать их в БД, чтобы пользовать при запуске не ждал, пока прогрузят его данные за эти сутки, хочу сделать, чтобы в определенное время суток скрипт на хосте сам выполнял эту операцию, а пользователю выдавались данные непосредственно из БД, возможно ли такое?

Comment: Гуглите про cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще для этого существует crontab.

Если охота хардкора, то:

1. Пишите скрипт в бесконечном цикле и запускаете из консоли.

   (php /path/script.php > /dev/null 2>&1) &
2. Смотрите только чтобы утечек не было в памяти и нагрузку на остальное железо мониторьте.

Comment: Надо не забывать еще выставить лимиты и таймауты, а то сервер сам грохнет скрипт по превышению лимита в значении `max_execution_time` в обоих случаях.